# Android Linear Layout Shape Issue

Tags: android-studio, background-image, shapes

I have the following in the android studio

[image]

However when I run it on the phone it comes like this. Why is it changing to oval shape and how to fix it?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Had to put the image under drawable and reference from there, that solved the issue. I was incorrectly referring to the image asset